# Is there a specific bash command to merge 2 files based on a delimiter?

Tags: bash, merge

I am trying to merge 2 files into 1 but in a specific way. I currently do this with nested while loops but want to know if there is an easier way or command. Imagine I have following files

File1

```
A

A
A
A
```

File 2

```
B
B

B
B
B
B

B

B
```

To ease the question, I have written A's and B's but the file can contain other lines.
These 2 files need to be merged and saved into a variable as it will be further used in my bash program, the variable must contain the following:

```
1:A
2:B
2:B
1:A
1:A
1:A
2:B
2:B
2:B
2:B
2:B
2:B
```

As you can see the files are merged together based on the newline, if one file has more groups (a group is multiple lines without an empty line) than they are just added after each other. Also there must be added a 1 or 2 based on which file the line is from. Is there an easy command  (**not awk**) that fixes this, instead of nested whiles?

MORE INFO EDIT

The 2 files must be merged with the delimiter "empty line" so you start with the first lines of file1 until an empty line, after that you add the lines of file2 until an empty line and so one. If one file has no more line, the other lines of the other file will just be added. The lines also must have an indication if the lines are from file 1 or file 2.

Comment: Not clear, could you please provide more details in your question, specially logic of getting sample output please, let us know once done please.

Comment: I added some more information.

Comment: Excellent question! But, doing this without awk would be more challenging than doing with awk

Comment: @fangio, shouldn't last 2 `B`s be like `1:B` since there are only 1 B coming continuous, sorry if I am wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
paste -z -d $'\n' <(
      sed 's/^$/\x00/;t;s/^/1:/' file1.txt) <(
      sed 's/^$/\x00/;t;s/^/2:/' file2.txt) |
sed 's/\x00//g;/^$/d'
```

The idea is to separate the "groups" by a zero byte, then use `paste` to join them. It works like this:

- empty lines are filled with zero bytes
- nonempty lines are prepended with the `1:` or `2:` prefix
- streams are `paste` joined on zero bytes with newline as the joined character
- After the `paste` we need to remove null bytes and empty lines

Comment: Try with `cat` instead of paste!

Comment: Why would I want to that? ! I need to second "block" from file2.txt come after the second "block" from file1.txt.

Answer (score 1):

Would you try the following:

```
# read file as a blank-line-separated array
readlines() {
    local file="$1"
    local -n array="$2"
    local num="$3"
    local line
    local i=0
    while IFS= read -r line; do
        if [[ -z $line ]]; then
            ((i++))
        else
            array[i]+="$num:$line"$'\n'
        fi
    done < "$file"
}

min() {
    local x="$1"
    local y="$2"
    if (( x < y )); then
        echo "$x"
    else
        echo "$y"
    fi
}

declare -a a b
readlines "file1" "a" "1"
readlines "file2" "b" "2"
m=$(min "${#a[@]}" "${#b[@]}")

# interleaving part
for (( i=0; i<m; i++ )); do
    echo -n "${a[i]}${b[i]}"
done

# remaining part
if (( ${#a[@]} < ${#b[@]} )); then
    for (( i=m; i<${#b[@]}; i++ )); do
        echo -n "${b[i]}"
    done
else
    for (( i=m; i<${#a[@]}; i++ )); do
        echo -n "${a[i]}"
    done
fi
```

Output:

```
1:A
2:B
2:B
1:A
1:A
1:A
2:B
2:B
2:B
2:B
2:B
2:B
```

**[EDIT]**

The script above *does* work but not interesting at all.
I've reconsidered to make use of `paste` command:

```
paste -d '' <(sed '/.\+/s/.\+/1:&/' file1 | tr '\n' '#' | sed 's/##/#\'$'\n/g') \
    <(sed '/.\+/s/.\+/2:&/' file2 | tr '\n' '#' | sed 's/##/#\'$'\n/g') \
    | tr -d '\n' | tr '#' '\n'
```

- It assumes the character `#` is not included in the file.
- It converts a single newline to a `#` at first.
- Then `paste` command is applied.
- Finally `#` is converted to a newline back again.

Comment: Good example to show why awk is the proper tool for such tasks. ++